# Storing query result from oracle database into MySql database on daily basis

Tags: mysql, oracle

My application has 2 databases, Oracle and MySQL. 
Now I need to store query result from table in oracle database into a table into MySQL database after every few hours.

[Here is the image that describes the above scenario.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYNDx.png)

I checked other similar questions but they are mostly on migration of entire database from Oracle to MySql not for "query result after every few hours" .

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by [creating a DB link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176580/how-to-link-mysql-db-to-oracle-db) from the Oracle server to the MySQL server. It's a bit involved, but once you have that working, you should be able to create a scheduler job to run the query every few hours and insert the results into a table over the DB link.

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
   job_name           =>  'store_my_result',
   job_type           =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action         =>  'BEGIN insert into "my_table"@mysqldblink select * from TestA; END;',
   start_date         =>  '05-Dec-2018 07:00:00 am',
   repeat_interval    =>  'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=3',
   enabled            =>  true);
end;
/
```

Obviously, test your anonymous PL/SQL block separately before creating a job using it.

Comment: Thank you. This helped.